# How to get more accurate parameter estimation with few samples?

Tags: time-series, dataset, anomaly-detection, parameterization

#### Context:

I have a time series on which I've trained an autoencoder model for anomaly detection (AD) purposes.

My time-series is 6 years worth of daily data, but for AD purposes, I am looking at one week window. This means I've only got 330 sub-sequences for my purposes.

I used 10% of those sub-sequences as my validation set, so 33 samples. It's not much, but it my model generalizes well to these few samples.

#### Problem:

For AD, I want to estimate the parameters of the residual distribution. I need these estimates in order to calculate an anomaly score using [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance). However, I don't think 33 samples is enough to estimate such parameters. Using the entire dataset seems like a bad idea, a sort of data leak.

#### Question:

Is it possible to get good parameter estimates with only these few samples?

I thought of adding "random" noise to some samples, but I'm pretty sure that would make the parameter estimates skewed as it might change the distribution in the wrong direction.

Comment: Do you have labeled data for validation? How did you choose your 33 samples for validation?

Comment: Your validation/test data is for using for performance evaluation, not for training/fitting on. That is what the training data is for (the 330-33).

Comment: Have you checked for trends or other distribution shifts in the data across the 6 years? How quickly do you want your model to adapt to shifts in the future?

Comment: @jonnor I am not training or fitting my encoder/decoder with my validation set. I am monitoring generalized performance of my autoencoder (as I mentioned in the question). Secondly, the validation set can be used to model the distribution of the residuals, again as mentioned in my post and as outlined here:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.00148.pdf.

Comment: @jonnor encoder-decoders do not operate on labeled data. It is a self-supervised method.

Comment: What is your evaluation metric? I am aware that autoencoders are not trained using labels. But labeled data is still the best for evaluation, by far.

Comment: Your post mentions Mahalanobis distance, however the paper does not? If you use Mahalanobis as a basis for anomaly scores, then the distribution for the Mahalanobis is estimated on the training set.

Comment: @jonnor, you are right. the paper is using MD squared. I'm playing with both. I don't think the distribution should be estimated on the training set. The paper outlines that it is done on the same validation set that is used for early stopping.

Comment: If you are referring to section 2.2. what they fit there is (I believe) an univariate normal distribution (on the reconstruction error). This in order to get a kind of "probability" instead of the arbitrary scaled reconstruction errors. 33 samples is probably OK enough for that.

Comment: If you suspect our validation set is not stable enough, consider time-series cross-validation to create many train/val/test splits, and look at how the statistics of the validation set varies